# SQL SERVER 2012 IF EXIST and IF NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query to check if a meter exist then do an update, it not do an insert to the monthly data table! The problem is I am confused about the syntax and I am not sure how to do it!

This is the database design. Let's say I have the meter number 2012345 how do I do that? Thank you[image]

Comment: Which database system? MySQL or SQL Server or both?

Comment: I am using both but if you want, consider it as a SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server (using just `name` as a demo, you'll of course want more fields)

```
MERGE meters AS target
USING (SELECT '2012345') AS source (meternumber)
ON (target.meternumber = source.meternumber)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET name='MeterUpdate#1', meternumber=source.meternumber
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (name, meternumber) VALUES ('MeterInsert#1', source.meternumber);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aa72/1).

In MySQL, create a unique index on meters(meternumber);

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bop ON meters(meternumber);
```

then insert/update using;

```
INSERT INTO meters (name, meternumber) VALUES ('MeterInsert#1', '2012345')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='MeterUpdate#1', meternumber='2012345';
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/197c5/1).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has MERGE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx that you can use as an UPSERT. Here's an example copied from the docs (Example A):

```
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
    VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
```